# Retrieving a whole Parse Column to a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

In my application I have an activity named Hospitals that extends an AppCompatActivity and I'm using parse to store my data. In parse I have a table called "Hospitals" with column called "Name"....I'm trying to retrieve the hospital names and display it in a list view for the users....but my code is only retrieving the first row from the table.

This is my code

```
public class Hospital extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String Hospitals = "Hospitals";
    private static final String HospitalName = "Name";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hospital);

        ListView list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);

        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery(Hospitals);{

            try{
                List<ParseObject> test = query.find();
                for(int x=0;x<test.size();x++){
                   final String[] str = {test.get(x).getString(HospitalName)};
                    final ArrayAdapter A1 = new   ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,str);
                    list1.setAdapter(A1);
                }
            }
            catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace code

> Problem is you are doing everything inside loop

You can use `HashMap<String, String>` for multiple column.

```
List<String> listHospital = new ArrayList<String>();
             HashMap<String, String> mapHospital = new HashMap<String, String>();
                try{
                    List<ParseObject> test = query.find();
                    for(int x=0;x<test.size();x++){
                        mapHospital.clear();
                        mapHospital.put("hospitalName", test.get(x).getString(HospitalName));
                        mapHospital.put("address", test.get(x).getString("addressColumnName"));
                        mapHospital.put("number", test.get(x).getString("addressColumnNumber"));
                        list1.add(mapHospital);
                    }
                    final ArrayAdapter A1 = new   ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list1);
                    list1.setAdapter(A1);
                }
                catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

You must have custom `Adapter`. if you want `key/value` means multiple column data

Comment: what should I add if i want to retrieve the hospital Address and Number in two other lists..???

Comment: the edited code didn't work...I'm having error with list.add(mapHospital);